# вопрос про php display error

Tags: php

здравствуйте, есть сайт, и поддомен, поддомен используется для тестирования обновлений, которые затем дописываются в каталог основного сайта

появилась нужда отключить полный вывод ошибок php.ini

```
#error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
#display_errors = On
#display_startup_errors = On
```

но нужно сделать так, чтобы на поддомене эти ошибки показывались, но ini_set как я читал, для parse error не работает, что можно предпринять в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения настроек PHP вы можете использовать еще как минимум два варианта:

1. `.htaccess` - если Apache httpd и PHP как его модуль - [подробнее](http://php.net/manual/ru/configuration.changes.php)
2. Непосредственная настройка из самого скрипта - [подробнее](http://php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php)

Смотрите сами, какой вариант вам больше подходит

Comment: ему нужно parse error, который нельзя настроить в самом скрипте непосредственно